# Why aren't my gifs animating?

Tags: support, images, image-upload

In my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44931759/why-does-it-take-such-a-long-time-for-ui-to-be-updated-from-background-thread) I have gifs, but they aren't animating. They work if I drag them straight into Chrome/Safari. They also work when I initially drag them onto the question, I mean I can see it working when I'm editing the question, but then once I submit the question it no longer animates. Even if I click on the edit to see if it works during animation, it still doesn't work. I've added gifs to my questions before.

I'm using the [licecap](http://www.cockos.com/licecap/) the same app the user of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24005242/5175709) has mentioned.

I'm not sure if this has something to do with SO or it's just about me creating gifs.

Is anyone else also experiencing similar issues?

Comment: GIF uploads are working for me, I tried to post [this GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0xXG.gif) as an answer and it did animate.

Comment: @BhargavRao wondering where you uploaded *that* GIF!? :D

Comment: @BhargavRao wrong.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You're using the large image modifier by appending an `l` to the end of the image ID in your path:

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/c81Vkl.gif
                               ^
```

Imgur only supports animations on the *original* image. If you use one of the image size modifications, the animation is removed completely. Removing that modifier displays the original image in its animated form. If you want to resize the image because it's too large *and* maintain the animation, you'll have to use HTML instead:

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/c81Vk.gif" width="400">
```

Comment: Woah TIL. Is this Imgur-wide? Or just for the SO namespace?

Comment: @Qix Just tried it on random Imgur pics, appending `l`, `m` and `s` changes their size. My mind is blown.

Comment: To clarify - that's a lowercase "L", not the number "1".

Comment: always relevant https://m.popkey.co/574b46/WxVke.gif

Comment: Okay, just found the docs on this: https://api.imgur.com/models/image

Comment: Stack Exchange [seems to allow slightly more than the base imgur modifiers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296077/sandbox-archive/230362#230362).

Comment: The extension is also irrelevant. The source image with a jpg extension: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c81Vk.jpg still animates. Allows you to sneakily add animated gifs in mediums that typically block gifs. Use responsibly.

Comment: @Compass what mediums block gifs? Any renown ones?

Comment: @Honey Some forums may "soft" ban gifs by only allowing PNG and JPG mostly to prevent annoying animated meme walls and silliness. Hence why I said use responsibly.

Comment: Is there something wrong with the modifiers? I feel like these days when I add an `m` or `l` the image doesn't change its size and I have to to do an `s` which is stupid.

Comment: @Honey They are currently broken. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314028/the-stack-imgur-service-is-no-longer-resizing-images-correctly).